# Не получается добавить панель табов

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Надо добавить в приложение на React и Typescript панель табов, но у меня на элементах:

```
 <Tab iconClassName="" linkClassName="Group 1">
 <Tab iconClassName="" linkClassName="Group 2">
```

исключение:

```
 TS2322: Type '{ children: Element; iconClassName: string; linkClassName: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'.   Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'.
```

Tabs.tsx

```
 import * as React from 'react';

 export default class Tabs extends React.Component<any, any> {
     constructor(props: any, context: any) {
         super(props, context);
         this.state = {
             activeTabIndex: 0,
         };
         this.handleTabClick = this.handleTabClick.bind(this);
     }

     handleTabClick(tabIndex: number) {
         this.setState({
             activeTabIndex: tabIndex === this.state.activeTabIndex ? this.state.activeTabIndex : tabIndex
         });
     }

     renderChildrenWithTabsApiAsProps() {
         return React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child: any, index) => {
            return React.cloneElement(child, {
                 onClick : this.handleTabClick,
                 tabIndex: index,
                 isActive: index === this.state.activeTabIndex
             });
         });
     }

     renderActiveTabContent() {         
         if (this.state.activeTabIndex !== undefined) {
             const {children} = this.props;
             const {activeTabIndex} = this.state;
             if (children != null) {
                 if (children[activeTabIndex]) {
                     return children[activeTabIndex].props.children;
                 }
             }
         }
     }

     render() {
           return (
             <div className="tabs">
                 <ul className="tabs-nav nav navbar-nav navbar-offices">
                     {this.renderChildrenWithTabsApiAsProps()}
                 </ul>
                 <div className="tabs-active-content">
                     {this.renderActiveTabContent()}
                 </div>
             </div>
         );
     }
 }
```

Tab.tsx

```
 import * as React from 'react';

 export interface Props {
     onClick      ?: Function;
     tabIndex     ?: Number;
     isActive     ?: Boolean;
     iconClassName?: String;
     linkClassName?: String;
 }

 function Tab ({
     onClick = function(){return; },
     tabIndex = '',
     isActive = '',
     iconClassName = '',
     linkClassName = ''
 }: Props) {
     return (
         <li className="tab">
             <a
            className={`tab-link ${linkClassName} ${isActive ? 'active' : ''}`}
                 onClick={(event) => {
                      event.preventDefault();
                      onClick(tabIndex);
                 }}
             >
                 {linkClassName}
                 <i className={`tab-icon ${iconClassName}`}/>
             </a>
         </li>
     );
 }

 export default Tab;
```

Stady.tsx

```
 import * as React from 'react';
 import Tabs from './Tabs';
 import Tab from './Tab';

 class Stady extends React.Component {
     render() {
         return (
         <Tabs>
             <Tab iconClassName="" linkClassName="Group 1">
                 <div className="tab-content">
                 </div>
             </Tab>
             <Tab iconClassName="" linkClassName="Group 2">
                 <div className="tab-content">
                 </div>
             </Tab>
         </Tabs>
       );
     }
 }

 export default Stady;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы передаете `<div className="tab-content">` в качестве `children` для `Tab` компонента, но `children` тип не указан в интерфейсе пропсов для `Tab`.

```
 import { ReactNode } from 'react'

 export interface Props {
   //...types
   children: ReactNode;
 }
```

Есть более лаконичный подход - использовать generic `FunctionComponent` для типизации пропсов, тип для children уже добавлен внутри `FunctionComponent`.

```
import { FunctionalComponent } from 'react'

 const Tab: FunctionalComponent<Props> = ({
   onClick = function(){return; },
   tabIndex = '',
   isActive = '',
   iconClassName = '',
   linkClassName = ''
 }) => { /.../ }
```